# App removido da playstore por violar a seção 4.4 do contrato de distribuição do desenvolvedor

Tags: android, licença, google-play

Recentemente enviei um app para playstore e ele estava funcionando normalmente desde semana passada.
Consegui milhares de usuários, estava tudo uma maravilha, até que hoje o google, sem mais nem menos, sem eu ter feito atualização nem nada, removeu o app da playstore (ele não foi suspenso, foi removido).
Motivo? "violation of section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement"

O app funciona da seguinte maneira:

- Usuário acessa o aplicativo com sua conta do instagram
- Usuário segue pessoas e ganha seguidores

O app em si só usa a api do instagram para login e mais nada. A parte do follow fica toda server-side.
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como proceder? Dicas pelo menos do que fazer para reenviar o app?

Obrigado

Comment: É uma infração sutil, porém grave. A sua base de usuários não é sua, é do Instagram. O seu app estava servindo como um "Instagram camuflado".

Answer (score 3):

## Contrato de distruibuição do desenvolvedor da Play Store

Segundo o artigo 4.4:

> O Desenvolvedor compromete-se a não participar de qualquer atividade com a Loja, incluindo o desenvolvimento ou a distribuição dos Produtos, que interfira, perturbe, prejudique ou **envolva** o **acesso indevido** a dispositivos, **servidores**, redes ou outras propriedades ou serviços de **terceiros**, incluindo, entre outros, os usuários Android, a Google ou qualquer operadora de rede móvel. Não é permitido usar as informações do cliente obtidas por meio da Loja para vender ou distribuir Produtos fora dela.

Note as partes que estão marcadas em negrito.

## O que aconteceu

Você utilizou uma API do Instagram e/ou outros servidores que é considerada de terceiros, e isso infringe o contrato, pelo que eu entendi.
Além disso, talvez o Instagram não tenha gostado da sua idéia, mas não tenho como confirmar isso.

Você pode tentar contatar os desenvolvedores do Android e ver se eles podem te botar com algum responsável da Google Play Store atrávés do IRC e outros meios de contato listados aqui: https://developer.android.com/support.html

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, mas agora já foi tarde... suspenderam até minha conta... :(